# Spring security and React

Tags: spring, security

I want to build web application in Spring Boot and React as frontend.
This application must have user authorization with roles and this is my question.
Are the Basic Spring Eecurity allow to share roles into frontend or I should use JWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use js framework (React etc.) so you need to generate and provide jwt (access & refresh token) from backend. Also you can use `keycloak` for implementing authorization functionality.